# Elasticsearch sort with a filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I two documents like this:

Doc 1:

```
{
   "inspections: [
      "startsOn" : {
         "utc" : "2019-01-06T02:00:00Z" // in the 'past'
       },
       "startsOn" : {
         "utc" : "2020-01-08T02:00:00Z" // in the 'future'
       }
   ]
}
```

Doc 2:

```
{
   "inspections: [
      "startsOn" : {
         "utc" : "2019-01-07T02:00:00Z" // in the 'past'
       },
       "startsOn" : {
         "utc" : "2020-01-06T02:00:00Z" // in the 'future'
       }
   ]
}
```

Now, some facts:

- Not using `nested` documents here. Everything is an object
- Both documents have 2 inspections, 1 of them in the 'past'

What i'd like to do:

- Sort documents by ones with an earliest inspection in the future. So, doc 2 should be first.

Here's my query:

```
GET /listings/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {      
      "should": [
        {
          "range": {
            "inspections.startsOn.utc": {
              "gte": "now/d"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    },
    {
      "inspections.startsOn.utc": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What's happening is they are both getting a score of `1` (because both have an inspection in the future), but doc 1 is getting a higher sort value for the second sort, since it has an 'earlier' inspection. (even though that inspection is in the past)

Any ideas how i can update my query? It's like i want the second sort to have a filter inside it? (so if the date is > today, then use it in the sort, otherwise don't?)

I've tried using Function Scoring, like so:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": {
            "terms": {
              <some other filter i need>
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": [
            {
              "range": {
                "inspections.startsOn.utc": {
                  "gte": "now/d"
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "weight": 2
        },
        {
          "filter": [
            {
              "range": {
                "inspections.startsOn.utc": {
                  "lte": "now/d"
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "weight": 1
        }
      ],
      "score_mode": "sum"
    }
  }
}
```

However the `score` is always 0.

Comment: Json structure of the document is wrong? Are you sure that is the correct representation?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a slightly different approach here: using `function_score` with a `decay` function. I believe is fits better because you have an origin value - `now/d` - and the closer to the origin the date value is, the better scoring should have. I haven't tested this in great detail, but it should get you started:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {      
      "should": [
        {
          "range": {
            "inspections.startsOn.utc": {
              "gte": "now/d"
            }
          }
        },
        {
            "function_score": {
                "exp": {
                    "inspections.startsOn.utc": {
                          "origin": "now/d", 
                          "scale": "90d"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If you have some counterexamples that will not work with the above query, please post them.

Answer (score 0):

In the first query you have a bool query with a single should clause, so every document matching the should clause will have a score of 1. So sorting on the basis of score wont really solve your problem.

In second query the problem is that one of the two parts of your function_score query is returning 0 and since you haven't assigned boost_mode value, it is "multiply" by default. So the final score will be the computation of

function_Score = Score(query) * Score(function1 + function2)

(*) [default multiply operation by boost_mode]

(+) [sum operation as specified in score_mode]

The multiplication operation here is due to the default boost_mode value which is "multiply" which you can change. 
You can check here for more:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html

Now if you can specify "boost_mode": "sum" just as you specified the score_mode and use exponential decay function instead of a range filter on inspections.startsOn.utc, your query will work just fine. This is how your query would look like:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score":
     {
       "query": {
         "bool": {      
         "filter": [
           {
             "range": 
               {
                 "inspections.startsOn.utc": 
                   {
                     "gte": "now/d"
                   }
               }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "exp": 
            {
              "inspections.startsOn.utc":
                {
                  "origin": now/d,
                  "scale": "100d"
                }
            },
          "weight": 2
        }
      ],
      "score_mode": "sum", 
      "boost_mode": "sum", 
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": 
      {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }]
  }
```

P.S. I would suggest you to read the function-score query link I shared. It will clear a lot of concepts regarding how scoring works.